# Expected primary-expression before '=' token

Tags: c++, typedef

here's a snippet of the code :

```
typedef int Biome;
typedef int Terrain;
typedef int Geo;

void mapGen(int mX, int mY /*max x and y map size*/)
{
    int seed;
    int costRemaining = 1;
    Biome biomeCur;
    Biome bChange = 0;
    Terrain terrainCur;
    Terrain tChange;
    Geo geoCur;
    Geo gChange;
    cout << "Please enter an integer to use as the generation seed";
    cin >> seed;
    srand(seed);
    biomeCur = rand() % MBIOME; //error is here
    terrainCur = rand() % MTERRAIN;
    geoCur = rand() % MGEO;
```

I can set biomeCur to 0 when I initialize it but I'm getting the above error on that line either way. 
I'm assuming that means it's not being declared properly but I don't see anything wrong with the code.

Comment: Did you `#include <stdlib.h>`?!

Comment: I suggest using `<random>` instead of `rand`.

Comment: I don't understand why someone downvoted. The only thing the user forgot to do was include his/her defines which is ok for a newbie in my mind. Please explain the downvote.

Comment: does <random> require any different sytax? or do I just replace everywhere I have rand() with it? I can't seem to find any documentation online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a compileable example out of your code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

typedef int Biome;
typedef int Terrain;
typedef int Geo;

//added by me
const int MBIOME = 10;
const int MTERRAIN = 10;
const int MGEO = 10;

void mapGen(int mX, int mY /*max x and y map size*/)
{
    int seed;
    int costRemaining = 1;
    Biome biomeCur;
    Biome bChange = 0;
    Terrain terrainCur;
    Terrain tChange;
    Geo geoCur;
    Geo gChange;
    cout << "Please enter an integer to use as the generation seed";
    cin >> seed;
    srand(seed);
    biomeCur = rand() % MBIOME; //error is here
    terrainCur = rand() % MTERRAIN;
    geoCur = rand() % MGEO;    
}


int main() {
    mapGen(1,1);
    return 0;
}
```

the only thing I changed was defining the `MBIOME` , `MTERRAIN`  and `MGEO`. I assume that they are the root of the problem.

EDIT: as you wrote in your comment you are using `#define MBIOME = 10`. That would mean that everywhere where you write MBIOME the preprocessor replaces it with `= 10`, if you do use a define write `#define MBIOME 10`. I would however suggest using a `const int` rather than a `#define`. `#define` uses the preprocessor which does not read syntax or know anything about scope so a const int is safer. Some people say that the preprocessor is more efficient than a const variable but they are still living in the 80's. Modern compilers can easily make the correct optimizations.

To illustrate why the preprocessor is risky imagine you wrote a function called `MBIOME()` in another namespace. The preprocessor would turn that into `10()` because it doesn't know about namespaces, it just replaces.

Comment: Can you explain how this helps?

Comment: That might actually be the problem, I'm using :
#define MBIOME = 10
What's the difference between these two?

Comment: @0x499602D2 it seems to have found the problem just fine.

Comment: Pretty much on spot, except for your last paragraph. The preprocessor, dumb as it is, only replaces full tokens. It wouldn't replace part of a token as you said. So no cookie here. ;)